# Is a filter necessary when using SpringSecurity?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring based project using SpringSecurity. This is my configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // just default options are fine
    }
}
```

My question is: Is it mandatory to include a filter definition in `web.xml` file like this?

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or should it work without it if I am using a recent enough Spring version?

My Application Server is Wildfly 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security implements the security by applying a servlet filter. So yes the filter is mandatory. As explained in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration), only time when it isn't required if you don't do servlet security which is in a standalone application or in a reactive web application.

When you are on a Servlet 3.0 container you can use the Spring Security supplied support classes to make it easier to register the filter. See [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer) of the reference guide. You can use the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` to register the filter for you.

If you are on an older servlet container you can still use the `web.xml` to do the same. Either way a filter named `springSecurityFilterChain` is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring Security 4 you can now use the Java-based configuration for your Security, so the `web.xml` is obsolete.

Comment: Nonetheless a filter is still needed, regardless of the way that is being configured.

Comment: @M.Deinum so, let me get this straight. I can configure with a Java-based file, but filter is ALWAYS needed. Correct? If that's the case, put that in an answer and I will accept that. OTOH: do you have some documentation/tutorial backing that up? I link would be great. Thanks!